# Mostrar Imagen de una Base de datos en una columna de un DataTable, C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, datatables

estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen en una columna de un datatable, pero no logro poder mostrarla, en mi columna de mi datatable pongo el codigo HTML img src, les muestro:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var cargandoGeneral = Swal.fire({
            title: 'Cargando productos...',
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            showCancelButton: false,
            showConfirmButton: false
        });
        table = $('#tablaProductos').DataTable({
            language: {
                url: "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Spanish.json",
            },

            ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("listar", "ProductosInventario")',

                complete: function (data) {
                    cargandoGeneral.close();
                }
            },

            columns: [
                {
                    //1
                    "name": "Codigo",
                    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {                       
                        return row.Codigo;
                    },
                },
                {
                    //2
                    "name": "Imagen",
                    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return '<img src="' + row.Imagen + '" style="height:50px;width:50px;" />';
                    },
                },
```

la imagen ya logro guardarla en una tabla de mi base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me la muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les muestro mi funcion de Javascript para el guardado de la imagen:

```js
function UploadImagen () {
        var file = $("#InputFile").get(0).files;
        var data = new FormData;
        data.append("ImageFile", file[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ProductosInventario/ImageUpload",
            data: data,
            //"Id": $('#Id').val(),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (Id) {
                $("#UploadedImage").append('<img src="/ProductosInventario/DisplayingImage?Id=' + Id + '"class=img-responsive thumbnail"/>');
            }
        });
    }
```

He visto ejemplos por internet de como las muestran pero aun no logro visualizar mi imagen.
quiero saber la manera correcta en la cual puedo mostrar mi imagen dentro de mi datatable.

si requieren mas info estoy al pendiente

Answer (score 1):

He podido solucionar mi problema al mostrar una imagen en mi datatable:

solo modifique mi codigo que tenia en mi columna de mi datatable a este codigo:

```js
//columna de mi datatable a mostrar la imagen
{
    //2
    'data': 'Imagen',
    'sortable': false,
    'searchable': false,
    'render': function (Imagen) {
        if (!Imagen) {
            return 'N/A';
        }
        else {
            var img = 'data:image/png;base64,' + Imagen;
            return '<img src="' + img + '" height="70px" width="90px" />';
        }
    }
},
```

y me mostro la imagen como queria.
gracias

Answer (score 0):

"columnDefs":[

```
            {
                "targets": 1,
                "sortable": false,
                "searchable": false,
                "render": function (imagen) {
                    if (!imagen) {
                        return "N/A";
                    }
                    else {
                        var img = imagen;
                        return '<img src="' + img + '" height="40px" width="40px" />';
                    }
                }
            }
```

]

Comment: Con las modificacion realizada funciona muy bien.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).